# Configuration of OptaPlanner with own Maven repository and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, optaplanner

How do I configure OptaPlanner with a Maven repository, which is located in the LAN / intranet and shares it's content via Windows network sharing.

What I tried to do is the following:

1. Downloaded the current version of optaplanner (6.1.0 Final)
2. Installed the JAR via `mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\temp\newLibs\optaplanner\optaplanner-core-6.1.0.Final.jar" -DgroupId=de.someCompany.3rdparty -DartifactId=de.someCompany.3rdparty.optaplanner-core -Dversion=6.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`
3. Update the local Maven repository in Eclipse (Update or Rebuild Index)
4. Add the recently installed package into the POM

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.someCompany.3rdparty</groupId>
  <artifactId>de.someCompany.3rdparty.optaplannerCore</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Implement some "real" and working stuff and also something to "solve":

> ```
>   SolverFactory solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(GlobalSettings.SOLVER_CONFIG);</li>
> ```
>
> After I've tried to run the application, I get this error msg:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConversionException
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SolverFactory.java:43)
    at de.someCompany.somePackageWhichImplementsOptaplanner.run.Run_SomeClass.main(Run_SomeClass.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

So I also have tried to add the XStream JAR (via official Maven Central) to the POM, but after all the same error is coming up.

What's the problem or what can I do to get OptaPlanner working on my own repository?

Answer (score 0):

You generated a pom.xml file for optaplanner-core, instead of using the official optaplanner-core pom.xml file. The latter contains `<dependencies>`, such as xstream. Take a look at the raw official optaplanner-core pom.xml in Maven Central to understand this better.

Use Nexus or Archiva to set up an internal maven repository. Don't do it like you're doing it now, that can only result in a corrupted maven repository, missing lots of important metadata (such as dependencies declarations).

Comment: I will try that and let you know about the status.

Comment: Ok, I've installed the repo (SonaType Nexus) and used the POM of the official website for installing it.
I also added the 3rd party repo on my eclipse m2 settings, but for e.g. the SolverFactory can't be resolved. If you need further information, let me know.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your project pom.xml, you should have a dependency on optaplanner-core. If that's there, try refreshing Eclipse. If that doesn't help, try IntelliJ to verify that the problem lies with eclipse and not your project pom.xml